# In a list of pairs, replace snds with median of all snds with the same fst

Tags: haskell, statistics

Given is a list of pairs. I want to replace the second element of all pairs with the median of the second elements of all pairs with the same first element.

For example:

```
[("a",1.0),("b",3.0),("a",2.0),("a",4.0)]
->
[("a",2.0),("b",3.0),("a",2.0),("a",2.0)]
```

The order of the elements in the resulting list is not important. So the following result would be equally valid:

```
[("a",2.0),("a",2.0),("a",2.0),("b",3.0)]
```

My current solution looks as follows:

```
import Control.Arrow
import qualified Data.Map as M

median :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
median xs | null xs  = error "empty list"
          | odd  len = xs !! mid
          | even len = meanMedian
                where  len = length xs
                       mid = len `div` 2
                       meanMedian = (xs !! mid + xs !! (mid+1)) / 2

solve :: [(String, Float)] -> [(String, Float)]
solve pairs = map replaceWithMedian pairs
    where
        medianMap = map (mapSnd (:[])) >>> M.fromListWith (++) >>> M.toList
                        >>> map (mapSnd median) >>> M.fromList
        mapSnd f (x, y) = (x, f y)
        replaceWithMedian (x, y) = (x, M.findWithDefault 0 x (medianMap pairs))

main :: IO ()
main = print $ solve [("a",1.0),("b",3.0),("a",2.0),("a",4.0)]
```

`solve` feels unnecessary long to me. I'm looking for more elegant/terse solution, not character-count-wise but with a simpler algorithm.

Comment: This being code review, answers will probably prioritize correctness, then efficiency, then brevity.

Comment: @200_success OK, thanks for the remark. Where should I post this if I want to play "algorithm beauty golf"?

Comment: We do plenty of that here too. You don't even have to ask for it. It's just that we will likely focus on other problems first if we spot them in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fixing things first

First of all, `median` is wrong:

```
median [1,2,3,4,5] /= median [3,1,4,5,2]
```

Both should return `3`, but on the first list `median` returns `3` and on the latter `4`. Make sure to `sort` your list, or state in the (currently missing) documentation that your list has to be sorted.
Also, using `!!` twice is rather slow. Instead, `drop` the first elements up to `mid` and then take the `mean`:

```
median :: (Fractional a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
median [] = error "median: empty list"
median xs
 | odd len  = xs' !! mid
 | otherwise = mean $ take 2 $ drop mid $ xs'
 where 
     len = length xs
     mid = len `div` 2
     xs' = sort xs

mean :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> Maybe a
mean xs = -- exercise; it's not trivial to get this right

-- Alternatively, just use meanDuo in median:
meanDuo :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
meanDuo [x,y] = -- ...
```

Also, if you use `error`, make sure to include the function's name in the error message; best practice include the completely qualified name, i.e.

```
error "Data.TupleMagic.median: empty list"
```

After all, there are (usually) no stack traces, and it's really nice to know *where* things went wrong. Note that you should add this behaviour in a documentation, since the type doesn't really tell what would happen on an empty list. Since `Fractional a` is also an instance of `Num`, any fixed number could be feasible. Alternatively use `Maybe a` as return type or `NonEmpty` as input.

### Use the tools you have at hand

`mapSnd` is `second` from `Control.Arrow`. Also, `Data.Map` is an instance of `Functor`, which means you can replace

```
M.toList >>> map (second f) >>> M.fromList
```

with

```
fmap f
```

Furthermore, be honest. Although `medianMap` is called `*Map`, it's actually a function. While GHC *might* call it only once, it's not guaranteed, so remember the map. And last, since you know that every key `x` will be contained in `toMap pairs`, you can use `Data.Map.!` instead of `Data.Map.findWithDefault`:

```
solve :: [(String, Float)] -> [(String, Float)]
solve pairs = map replaceWithMedian pairs
  where
    toMap     = map (second pure) >>> M.fromListWith (++) >>> fmap median
    medianMap = toMap pairs
    replaceWithMedian (x, _) = (x, medianMap M.! x)
```

Furthermore, there's usually no reason to use `Float` nowadays, unless you've checked

- that it's faster,
- that it's reduced accuracy fulfils your needs, and
- you're having memory constraints (which usually also contradicts `String` and lists).

Instead, `Double` is used most of the time.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you very much. Things like `second`, `pure` and `fmap` are exactly what I was looking for. And you explained them and other things very well. But why is `mean` not trivial to implement? Is the following not correct? https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/f4ea615dde527e8b2007

Comment: Btw, the median function came from [rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Median). I should have checked for input assertions like sortedness.

Comment: The gist implementation is fine for small lists (e.g. the two-element list in this example). But try `mean [1..10^7]` or similar large lists.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few notes about current implementation of `solve`:

- As you are using `Control.Arrow`, `mapSnd` is already here, see [`second`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:second).
- Using `M.findWithDefault` can lead to hiding implementation errors because it replaces "key not found" error (which could not occur if code is correct) with random value. I would suggest using [`Map.!`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:-33-) as it explicitly states that "not found" is not expected.
- `medianMap` is a pure function and it is applied only to `pairs` but GHC is not smart enough to calculate `medianMap pairs` only once. That means you are building new map of medians for each element of `pairs`. You can `let mapOfMedians = medianMap pairs` to be sure that it is calculated only once.

It is also possible to `solve` little bit more concisely:

```
solve
  = concatMap (\(k,xs) -> replicate (length xs) (k, median xs))
  . M.toList
  . foldl' (\m (k,v) -> M.insertWith' (++) k [v] m) M.empty
```

This could also be a bit faster as it does not traverse map of medians on each pair.

Answer (score 1):

**Helper function**

Your code feels complicated because you did not write a helper function, I suggest the function:

```
allLookUps :: Eq b1 => b1 -> [(b1, b)] -> [b]
```

Example usage:

```
*Main> allLookUps 4 [(4, 314), (0,5), (4, 7)]
[314,7]
```

To find all the second items that match to the first.

Using it, `solve` is very easy, we just apply it to all the first items and create the result tuples:

```
solve xs = map (\x -> (x, median $ allLookUps x xs)) $ map fst xs
```

**Explicit pattern matching**

`null xs` requires some thinking and confuses imperative programmers about another null.

I suggest explicit pattern matching to be immediately obvious:

```
median []  = error "empty list"
-- etc...
```

**Be general with your types**

`solve` can have a way more general type than you wrote, look:

```
solve :: (Eq b, Fractional b1) => [(b, b1)] -> [(b, b1)]
```

I see no reason to restrict it to `String` and `Float`.

Comment: Being general is not always a good advice as polymorphic functions have some overhead. E.g see https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Overloading and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854866

Comment: @maxtaldykin Especially in functional programming, be careful with premature optimizarion. In the page says "inside tight loops"